# Cannot import installed module using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, reportlab

I'm trying to import Canvas from the ReportLab module using PyCharm as my IDE. 
[image: import statements]

I get an Import Error on that line.

[image: Import error]

[image: Installed modules]
ReportLab is installed in this environment and it works outside of PyCharm on terminal. Any ideas to help me get this working?

Comment: To copy something from text editor, use Ctrl+C. Terminal applications are usually allow copying through context menu

Comment: @myaut I'm asking why I'm unable to import Canvas from ReportLab module that's installed

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated virtualenv on your terminal prompt before you try to run kivy? Also run command `which kivy` to see you are using a correct Kivy installation if you have multiple installations.